# Invalid 8086 assembly statement

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have seen a sentence in assembly language and I don't know why it is wrong.
Here it is:

```
mov cx, ch
```

.Why is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your instruction is wrong because  `CX` is 16 bit and `CH` is 8 bit (it's the higher 8 bits in CX

Comment: But if cx is 16 bits does not enter ch which is 8 bits in it?

Comment: The registersize for the sourceregister and the targetregister have to be the same number of bits.

Comment: Ok,I apreciate your answer.If you want I want to ask you some more questions about x86 assembly,I have a written paper this week and I have some doubts about something.

Answer (score 0):

Your single line `mov cx,ch` can be wrong in 2 ways.
If the instruction is indeed MOV then the *operands* are wrong because they need to have the same size. This is what Dirk Wolfgang Glomp said.
But if the operands are correct then the *instruction* itself is wrong and should be replaced with MOVZX or MOVSX.

ps How strict should we interpret the tag **8086** ? (*x86 assembly* is not limited to 16 bit)

Comment: I believe the tag [tag:8086] is for 8086 assembly in either real-mode or 16bit-protected mode (although I would prefer the currently unused tag [tag:80286] for that).